# How to load specific CSS if free shipping is available?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is there a way to conditionally apply to the subtotal the CSS classes below based on free shipping?

```
.free-shipping-text {
content: "Hurray Free Shipping";
}

.nonfree-shipping-text {
content: "Get Free Shipping over ₹ 1000"
}
```

if subtotal price is less than ₹ 1000 then nonfree-shipping-text CSS should call and when greater than ₹ 1000 then free-shipping-text CSS should call.

```
global $woocommerce;
$shipping_methods = $woocommerce->shipping->load_shipping_methods();
if($shipping_methods['free_shipping']->enabled == "yes")
{
.free-shipping-text CSS should call
}        
else
.nonfree-shipping-text CSS should call
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the classes in your html. Then you create 2 stylesheet CSS files that you enqueue conditionally.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $shipping_methods = $woocommerce->shipping->load_shipping_methods();
    if($shipping_methods['free_shipping']->enabled == "yes")
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'stylefreeshipping', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/free-shipping.css' );
    }        
    else{
        wp_enqueue_style( 'styleNOfreeshipping', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/no-free-shipping.css' );
    }
} );
```

However for that to work everytime they add products and surpass the 1000 units the page should be reloaded. This is the only way it'll work with PHP. If you use AJAX in that process then you should better use JavaScript. That will give a more dynamic experience to the user.

More on [enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) style.

Editing the answer for javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.classList.add("mystyle");   //add
  element.classList.remove("mystyle");  //remove
}
```

[To add a class.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp)

[To remove a class.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp)

However that means that you need to grab the monetary value and add an event listener to it. Then on every event change you check if the value is more than 1000 so you add the needed class and you remove the other and vice versa when you drop from 1000.

Comment: I am using the custom message to mini cart header . Is this work as ajax means after getting subtotal amount equal or greater than free shipping value ( i.e. ₹ 1000 ) it should changed the message with .free-shipping-text @billybadass

Comment: @rowoc edited the answer to include javascript way.